# Twitter summary card with large image not showing the complete Image

Tags: twitter

I am trying to share the following blog post on twitter.

```
https://theramblingmind.com/2020/06/20/edhayaum-our-thadavai-by-rajesh-kumar/
```

The shared URL on twitter looks as follows.

```
https://twitter.com/Jagannathan6/status/1274382615034785792
```

However, the large image displayed in twitter is cropped and the only the lower half is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is not in the correct dimensions for a [summary large image card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary-card-with-large-image):

> A URL to a unique image representing the content of the page. You
> should not use a generic image such as your website logo, author
> photo, or other image that spans multiple pages. Images for this Card
> support an aspect ratio of 2:1 with minimum dimensions of 300x157 or
> maximum of 4096x4096 pixels. Images must be less than 5MB in size.
> JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of
> an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.

You'll need to provide an image that is in 2:1 (landscape) ratio.